# Why ufw blocks connection when they're allowed?

Tags: linux, firewall, ufw

I have the following set of rules

```
sudo ufw status numbered
Status: active

     To                         Action      From
     --                         ------      ----
[ 1] 41337/tcp                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere
 ...
[15] 8080/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[16] 4001/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere
```

But I'm still getting `UFW BLOCK` log entries in `dmesg`.

```
[Mon Jan 20 13:28:42 2020] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=74:xx:xx:xx:e5:xx:xx:45:cb:59:xx:b0:08:xx SRC=49.XXX.XXX.XXX DST=192.168.XXX.XXX LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=112 ID=894 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=4001 DPT=4001 WINDOW=8192 RES=0x00 ACK SYN URGP=0
[Mon Jan 20 13:28:54 2020] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=74:xx:xx:xx:e5:xx:xx:45:cb:59:xx:b0:08:xx SRC=113.XXX.XXX.XXX DST=192.168.XXX.XXX LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=50 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=15559 DPT=4001 WINDOW=0 RES=0x00 RST URGP=0
```

Why is that?

**EDIT**

Full table:

```
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), deny (routed)
New profiles: skip

     To                         Action      From
     --                         ------      ----
[ 1] 1337/tcp                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 2] 8333/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 3] 53/udp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 4] 51413/tcp                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 5] 9117/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 6] 53/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 7] 8090/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 8] 6881/udp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 9] 80/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[10] 443/tcp                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[11] 5351/udp                   ALLOW IN    17X.XXX.0.0/16
[12] 5351/udp                   ALLOW IN    17X.XXX.0.0/16
[13] 5351/udp                   ALLOW IN    17X.XXX.0.0/16
[14] 8084/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[15] 8080/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[16] 4001/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[17] 5001/tcp                   ALLOW IN    10.X.X.X/24
```

Comment: Did you run `ufw reload` after setting those rules?

Comment: @Panki No I didn't but now after trying it out I'm still getting the `UFW BLOCK`s

Comment: UFW checks authorizations in sequence and the first one that matches win. So you should show us the whole UFW status output. The problem is very likely in lines 2..14. If you want to add lines you usually want to prefix them with `INSERT 1`so that they are at the top and are checked first.

Comment: @xenoid Added full output. I don't understand how that would change it since they are all `ALLOW` rules.

Comment: view `iptables`. Maybe some running program has added rules directly there.

Comment: Well I do run `docker` which by default adds rules via iptables but why would the log entry contain: `[UFW BLOCK]` then?